# Where Clause: Compact byte storage day of week

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named `AutoEventDays` in my *MySQL* table named `WebEvents`. It stores values such as the following:

```
0010000
0111110
```

Each digit represents a day of the week, beginning with Sunday. A zero means "no invitation will be sent on that day" and a one means "an invitation will be sent on that day". So `0010000` means "send an invitation on Tuesday only". And `0111110` means "send an invitation M-F".

What is the most efficient way to construct the `where clause` so that if the `1` matches **today** (as determined by server time), that row will be returned, otherwise not. So for example:

```
On Tuesdays, this record will be returned: 0010000 
On all non-Tuesdays this record will NOT be returned: 0010000 
On M-F this record will be returned: 0111110 
On weekends this record will NOT be returned: 0111110
```

**Important: `AutoEventDays` is an ordinary char(7), not a number or binary.**

My thinking has been taking me down the road of ugly and complex and repetitive where clause...and I know somebody on stack will have an efficient way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` with underscores and ones to match the string:

```
SELECT *
FROM WebEvents
WHERE
    (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Sunday'    AND AutoEventDays LIKE '1______')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Monday'    AND AutoEventDays LIKE '_1_____')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Tuesday'   AND AutoEventDays LIKE '__1____')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Wednesday' AND AutoEventDays LIKE '___1___')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Thursday'  AND AutoEventDays LIKE '____1__')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Friday'    AND AutoEventDays LIKE '_____1_')
OR  (DAYNAME(CURDATE())='Saturday'  AND AutoEventDays LIKE '______1')
```

This approach can be simplified if you create a seven-row lookup table with masks for days:

```
CREATE TABLE DayMaskLookup (DayName VARCHAR(10), Mask CHAR(7))
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Sunday',    '1______')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Monday',    '_1_____')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Tuesday',   '__1____')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Wednesday', '___1___')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Thursday',  '____1__')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Friday',    '_____1_')
INSERT INTO DayMaskLookup VALUES ('Saturday',  '______1')
```

Now your query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM WebEvents e
JOIN DayMaskLookup m ON e.AutoEventDays LIKE m.Mask
WHERE m.DayName = DAYNAME(CURDATE())
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight: Your answer looks promising, but as mentioned in post, `AutoEventDays` is a column, not a table. The table is named `WebEvents`. Could you adjust your answer accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: Bingo! Thank you dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are stored as (binary) numbers (you didn't tell) you could use a Bitwise AND. Monday = 64, Tuesday = 32, etc.

where InvitationMask & Tuesday > 0

Comment: Sorry, it's text, not binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dayofweek()` and bit operations:

```
where mask & (1 << (7 - dayofweek(curdate())) )
```

Why would you store a mask as a string?  That seems wierd.  In any case, you can do:

```
where substr(mask, 7 - dayofweek(curdate()), 1) = '1'
```

This seems much simpler than the other solutions.

Comment: Mask is a string, not a number. Otherwise it would be hard to store leading zeros from OP’s example. See OP’s comment to the other answer.